# How to find only one process Name using regex in linux server

Tags: regex, linux

I have the below process running on the server. I need to get only vehicledetailformatter-1.0.jar process name. But when i am trying to run the below command it is retreivng unwanted process too. Please see below.

```
ps aux | grep "[v]ehicledetailformatter-1.0.jar"
52843     4190  0.1  1.2 1405336 97000 ?       Sl   Feb14   1:35 /data01/appserver/jboss1/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/jre1.8.0_112/bin/java -jar vehicledetailformatter-1.0.jar
52843     4259  0.1  0.9 1404388 77860 ?       Sl   Feb14   1:36 /data01/appserver/jboss1/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/jre1.8.0_112/bin/java -jar nonvehicledetailformatter-1.0.jar
52843     4294  0.1  1.1 1405408 96296 ?       Sl   Feb14   1:37 /data01/appserver/jboss1/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/jre1.8.0_112/bin/java -jar vehicledetailformatter-1.0.jar
52843     4751  0.1  1.2 1405744 100252 ?      Sl   Feb14   1:35 /data01/appserver/jboss1/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/jre1.8.0_112/bin/java -jar vehicledetailformatter-1.0.jar
52843    21402  0.1  0.9 1402260 75372 pts/3   Sl   Feb14   1:06 /data01/appserver/jboss1/jboss-eap-6.4/bin/jre1.8.0_112/bin/java -jar vehicledetailformatter-1.0.jar
```

But the jar version in future will get to updated to someother one. So in the script i am using jar file as a variable like jar_file=""vehicledetailformatter*.jar"

Could you please help me in getting the correct process name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ps aux |grep " vehicledetailformatter-1.0.jar"
```

(note the space inside quotes).

About the version number changing, this works:

```
ps aux |grep " vehicledetailformatter-[0-9]*\.[0-9]*\.jar"
```

Also note the `\` backslash before the dot: strictly speaking it should be used even in the first example, also a trailing `$` in the regexp would not be bad.

There are other possibilities, but a reading about regexp is needed.

Comment: Thank you linuxfan. Yes you are right. Need to learn more about regexp....

Answer (score 0):

A match for the whitespace in front of your processname forces the regex to match the whole name, adding a .* to eat ALL versiong info and anchoring the regex to the end of the line will certainly capture only your requested processes

```
ps aux | grep " vehicledetailformatter-.*\.jar$"
```